# Manipulating a list of tuples

Tags: python, generator

I have a list of two-element tuples: `(object, timestamp)`.

I want to make a generator that returns lists where each list contains tuples that share the same timestamp.

Another demand is that the first list the generator returns is the list of the earliest timestamp.

For convenience let's assume timestamps are natural numbers: `1, 2, 3, ...`.

Is there any built-in tool of Python for such thing or the solution is the naive implementation?

Comment: What's wrong with sorting and using `itertools.groupby()`?

Comment: What Igancio said along with `sort or sorted` function would do what you are asking.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thank you too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the help of `operator` and `itertools`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby   

def grouped(mytuples):
    for timestamp, items in groupby(sorted(mytuples, key=itemgetter(1)),
                                    key=itemgetter(1)):
        yield timestamp, list(items)
```